# Adding a substring to omit a part of the output

Tags: java

Below is my code...
The code below is taking a .txt file of some radiation read outs.  My job is to find the max number of counts per minute in the file within 5 counts.
I'e got it working, but I need to omit the part of the line, so I thought I could make this piece of the code:

```
/* String temp = new String(data) 
* temp=list.get(i);
* System.outprintln(temp.substring(0,16) +"   ");
*/
```

and integrate it in.  I keep trying several cases, and am not thinking.  Any advice?

```
`import java.util.*;
//Import utility pack, *look at all classes in package.
import java.io.*;
//Good within directory.
public class counterRadiation {

private static String infile = "4_22_18.txt";
//Input
private static String outfile = "4_22_18_stripped.txt";
private static Scanner reader;
//Output


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    //throw exception and then using a try block

    try {
        //Use scanner to obtain our string and input.
        Scanner play = new Scanner(new File(infile));

        /* String temp = new String(data)
         * temp=list.get(i);
         * System.outprintln(temp.substring(0,16) +"   ");
         */

        Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                new FileOutputStream(outfile), "utf-8"));

        String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        play.useDelimiter(lineSeparator);



        while (play.hasNext()) {
            String line = play.next();

            if (line.matches(dataList)) {
                writer.write(line + "\r\n");
            }
        }
        writer.close();
        play.close();



        try {
            reader = new Scanner(new File(infile));
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
                list.add(reader.nextLine());
            }
            int[] radiCount = new int[list.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size();i++) {
                String[] temp = list.get(i).split(",");
                radiCount[i] = (Integer.parseInt(temp[2]));
            }
            int maxCount = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < radiCount.length; i++) {
                if (radiCount[i] > maxCount) {
                    maxCount = radiCount[i];
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0;i < list.size() ;i++) {
                if(radiCount[i] >= maxCount - 4) {
                System.out.println(list.get(i)+"  "+ radiCount[i]);



                }
            }





        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}`
```

Comment: What is your **Input** String and What is expected **Output**?

Comment: "and am not thinking" I'm sorry, but thinking is a prerequisite to getting help.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not quite clear what you want to get rid of you could use `.indexOf(String str)` to define the first occurrence of the sub-string you want to exclude. For example in your code:

```
     String data = "useful bit get rid of this";
     int index = data.indexOf("get rid of this");
     System.out.println(data.substring(0,index) + "are cool");
      //Expected result:
      //"useful bits are cool"
```

from [Java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)